# C# WPF DataGrid Header Style Not Updating after On Click event handling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a C# WPF project using a `DataGrid` to display a `DataTable`.
The DataTable was populated by reading in a CSV file (unknown number of headers) and populating it using the CSVHelper nuget package.

```
using (FileStream? stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
{ 
    using (StreamReader? reader = new(stream))
    using (CsvReader? csv = new(reader, csvConfiguration))
    {
        using CsvDataReader? dr = new(csv);
        dataTable.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

I am displaying this DataTable using the following XAML setup.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
            AlternationCount="2"
            CanUserSortColumns="False"
            AutoGeneratingColumn="Data_AutoGeneratingColumn"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
            Loaded="Data_Loaded"
          >

    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DataGridColumnHeader_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I have added code to the **Loaded** Event for the `DataGrid` that cycles through all the `DataGridColumn` entries from `DataGrid.Columns` and will set their `HeaderStyle` depending on if they exist in a `List<string>` to either:

1. SelectedHeaderStyle
2. UnSelectedHeaderStyle

```
foreach (DataGridColumn column in grid.Columns)
{
    string headerText = column.Header.ToString();
    if (cSVConfigureContext.SelectedColumns.Contains(headerText))
    {
        column.HeaderStyle = selectedHeaderStyle;
    }
    else
    {
        column.HeaderStyle = notSelectedHeaderStyle;
    }
}
```

I am also handling the **Click** event for TargetType `DataGridColumnHeader` which will toggle the `HeaderStyle` between 1 and 2.

```
private void DataGridColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var columnHeader = sender as DataGridColumnHeader;
    if (columnHeader != null)
    {
        string headerText = columnHeader.Content.ToString();
        if (cSVConfigureContext.SelectedColumns.Contains(headerText))
        {
           columnHeader.Style = notSelectedHeaderStyle;

           cSVConfigureContext.SelectedColumns.Remove(headerText);
        }
        else
        {
            columnHeader.Style = selectedHeaderStyle;
            cSVConfigureContext.SelectedColumns.Add(headerText);
        }
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[image: Header Selected and unSelected Result]

This part all seems to work.
*However*, adding a "Reset Headers" button to return to a default set of selected columns, is where things are not working.

If I load the window with the `DataGrid` and press the **Reset** button (which runs the same code used in the **Loaded** event, it works fine. But if I first click on any header to switch its state, the style on the column header does not change. I see the change in the `SelectedColumns` list of strings but no visual update in the DataGrid until I close that window and re-open a new DataGrid. But I can still click headers to change their state.

I've spent a couple hours googling options for forcing a redraw of the column headers but so far no luck.

Any ideas why the **Reset** button doesn't work after a **Click** event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas why the Reset button doesn't work after a Click event?

The `Style` of the `DataGridColumnHeader` apparently overrides or take precedence over the `HeaderStyle` of the `DataGrid`.

Setting the `Style` property of all `DataGridColumnHeader` elements to `null` before setting the `HeaderStyle` property of the `DataGrid` will probably fix your issue.

Comment: Great direction! I changed the `private void DataGridColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` section to set `columnHeader.Column.HeaderStyle` instead of `columnHeader.Style` because it is not possible to nicely get a `DataGridColumnHeader` from a DataGrid or DataGridColumn (datagrid.columns). Ensuring I used HeaderStyle in all locations solved the issue! Thank you @mm8